# Getting password authentication failed upon connecting to postgres db from pgadmin 3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, heroku

I have an app deployed on **Heroku** that has a postgresql db added as an add-on, upon connecting to it from pgadmin3 for the first time it is getting connected but then afterwards on subsequent connections **most of the times** it is showing an error dialog and rarely it gets connected. I even did the changes that were suggested in the error dialog. I have no idea regarding this ambiguity.

> The server doesn't grant access to the database: the server reports 
>   FATAL: password authentication failed for user "bcueventxumaik" FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10x.8x.80.2xx", user "bcueventxumaik", database "d69dc8daX899vX", SSL off
>
> To access a database on a PostgreSQL server, you first have to grant primary access to the server for your client (Host Based Authentication). PostgreSQL will check the pg_hba.conf file if a pattern that matches your client address / username / database is present and enabled before any SQL GRANT access control lists are evaluated.
>
> The initial settings in pg_hba.conf are quite restrictive, in order to avoid unwanted security holes caused by unreviewed but mandatory system settings. You'll probably want to add something like 
>   host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5
>
> This example grants MD5 encrypted password access to all databases to all users on the private network 192.168.0.0/24. 
>   You can use the pg_hba.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III to edit the pg_hba.conf configuration file. After changing pg_hba.conf, you need to trigger a server configuration reload using pg_ctl or by stopping and restarting the server process.